# How to get JavaFX 2.0 visibility event on Pane?

Tags: events, properties, javafx-2, visibility, pane

After several tries and researches, I have not managed to get visibility event from Pane. The below sample seems to be my best try, but it does not work.
Any working propositions are welcomed.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class VisibilityTestMain extends Application {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    VisibilityTestMain.launch(args);
}

@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
    Pane root = new Pane();
    ChangeListener<Boolean> visibilityListener = new ChangeListener<Boolean>() {

        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> arg0, Boolean oldValue, Boolean newValue) {
            System.out.println("####");
        }
    };
    root.visibleProperty().addListener(visibilityListener);

    Button button = new Button("Hello");
    button.setTranslateX(10);
    button.setTranslateY(20);
    root.getChildren().add(button);

    stage.setScene(new Scene(root, 50, 50));
    stage.show();

}
```

}

Comment: I don't think you add the Pane to your Scene. Am i wrong?

Comment: @Fabinout Normally yes I do, as the button is visible when I run it. It should be performed with the line : `stage.setScene(new Scene(root, 50, 50));`

Comment: what exactly are you trying to achieve by listening on the visibleProperty? Because the isVisible returns true right after the construction of the pane and this never changes.

Comment: @Sebastien I want to performed some functional features. In other librairies, like swing, this is a common and basic event.

Comment: @Jakez How do you want to reach the visibily events if you don't switch this visibility elsewhere?

Comment: @Fabinout Why should I perform a switch on visibility as it is already visible?

Comment: @Jakez When you created the Pane, its visibleProperty was true, and didn't change, so you couldn't access your listenner on the visibleProperty

Comment: @Fabinout Yes I know @Sebastien said the same. The problem is that the visibleProperty is not set at the correct moment when it is really visible. Your solution is working, but it is a shame to have the following code 
`  stage.setScene(new Scene(root, 50, 50));
  stage.show();
  root.setVisible(false);  
  root.setVisible(true);`

Comment: If the container isn't visible, the items (although visible) inside it wont be seen. So yeah, the method isn't accessed at the construction of the object. I'm not sure I understand what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you never change the visibility of your Pane, thus your listener is never reached.

Try this piece of code instead:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public class VisibilityTestMain extends Application {

public static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(VisibilityTestMain.class);
public static void main(String[] args) {
    VisibilityTestMain.launch(args);
}

@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
    final Pane root = new Pane();
    root.visibleProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>() {
        @Override
        public void changed(final ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> observableValue, final Boolean aBoolean, final Boolean aBoolean2) {
            System.out.println("####");
            //To change body of implemented methods use File | Settings | File Templates.
        }
    });

    Button button = new Button("Hello");
    button.setTranslateX(10);
    button.setTranslateY(20);
    root.getChildren().add(button);
    button.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(final ActionEvent actionEvent) {
            root.setVisible(false);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();  //To change body of catch statement use File | Settings | File Templates.
            }
            root.setVisible(true);
        }
    });

    stage.setScene(new Scene(root, 50, 50));
    stage.show();

}
}
```

Now you can see that the visible property of your Pane is accessed every time you click your button.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but what about the first display?

Comment: @Jakez Let's be clear here, you weren't able to reach the visibility event in the first place, were you?

Comment: In a strict functional point of view, my need is very simple: It is to receive event on all new pane visibility changes (in an operator point of view, not on a “visibleProperty” point of view), from the first one to the last one. I have already used such feature in the past, on other libraries; I have even implemented some myself. Unfortunately, it seems not implemented correctly in JFX because the first effective display is not raised.

Comment: @Fabinout I am quite sure that the questioner would like to know how he (she) could handle an event only when the panel application become visible. This type of event is initially generated by JavaFX program when a graphical interface is mounted. Also, adding a 1 second pause in the task of JavaFX application can seriously compromise the performance of the application of the questioner.